# Long running tasks in Objective-C

Tags: ios, multithreading

I'm trying to figure out how to do log running tasks in Objective-C (iOS) in a way that is not gonna hang the UI thread, kinda like background workers or the TPL in .Net.

I'm looking for a way to handle this kind of work in a maintainable way that is considered a best practice for iOS dev?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways you can do that, like `NSThread`, `NSOperation`/`NSOperationQueue` classes or `GCD`. Example code (GCD):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    //background work
});
```

You can read about it here: [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html)

Comment: +1, although NSThread should be the last resort. GCD takes care of thread management more efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

For GCD, try this test:  (Also refer to Apple's doc as Adam and Martin R have suggested.

```
- (IBAction)dispatchQPressed:(id)sender 
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)
        {
            NSLog(@"Running in background thread concurrently: %i", i);
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i<200; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"run in main thread:%i", i);
    }
}
```